# Which user last modified a record in NetSuite?

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I'm trying to list the user/employee who last modified a Customer record in NetSuite, but I'm not seeing any field or join field that can provide this information. How can I see *who*—either an automation service user or employee user—last modified a record?

I've looked into the following fields but they don't seem to provide what I'm looking for.

- **System Notes Fields...** may contain zero or *multiple* records that match the Last Modified date on a customer. Not reliable for determining who last touched a record.
- **Workflow History Fields...** doesn't contain any info on users
- **User Fields...** seems to be fields related to the current user, not to the user who touched a given record

Answer (score 3):

I've always just run a search on the record's system notes, sorting by date descending, and only grabbing the first response.  If you are looking for the last time a specific field is modified, you can simply add that into the search filters.

That is assuming that you are trying to do this is SuiteScript.  Otherwise, in the UI, you just look at the system notes sublist.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, [W3BGUY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/611751/w3bguy), but I'm seeing a situation where the **Last Modified** is almost 1 hour later than the most recent **System Notes Date** for that record. Do you know why there may be a discrepancy like this?

Comment: Wow...  No, I have not seen that.  I would contact NetSuite about that one.  I would also look at any integrations that you may have running..?  Maybe one of those found a way to edit without properly showing up...  Other than that, I could only think that it might be a timezone issue.

Comment: I agree with W3BGuy I have never seen that kind of delay. System notes has always been very reliable for me. Although if a user saves and a client script or even some user event scripts set something it may act like the user did it. That's my biggest issue